# Inheritance in Java and override parent class constructor

Tags: java, inheritance

Can somebody explain me why you don't need to override all constructors that defined in Super class. Example:

```
Public Employee{
    String naam;
    String adres;

    Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    Employee(String naam, String adres) {
        this(name);
        this.adres =adres;
    }
}

public Person extends Employee {
    String name;
    String adres;

    Person(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

If I don't override the first constructor, I got a compiler error.

Comment: Your constructor needs a parameter: `name`. In Java, only a non-argument constructor is by generated by defaut.

Comment: How to override a constructor ?????

Answer (score 4):

have a look at name Hiding, the one you didnt implement wont be used.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: Thank you for answering the actual question, instead of why a constructor is needed at all, like everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

By default, a non-argument constructor is generated by the compiler for every class **as long as there is no adjacent constructor manually specified**.

By default, if you don't specify any constructor in `Person` class, the compiler will generate this one:

```
public Person extends Employee{
  String name;
  String adres;
  Person(){
    super();   //there is no constructor with no-arg in your parent class, therefore compilation obviously fails !
  }
```

Note that your `Employee` class "disabled" the default generation of the non-arg constructor since it provides **at least** one constructor with parameters **and NO constructor with no parameters**, explaining that the preceding generated code does not compile.

Therefore, you will need a way to pass the parameter `name` to the `Employee` class.
The only way to do this is to precise a "custom" constructor, meaning manually hard-coded, that would dispatch the parameter to the parent's constructor.

That's why this is the correct solution (not yours):

```
public Person extends Employee{
  Person(String name){
    super(name);
  }
```

Note that making `Person` extending an `Employee` makes no sense, it would be more logical to have the `Employee` extending the `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically because when a subclass is initialized, it always needs also to initialize its superclass, i.e. call a constructor of the superclass.

If you not call any explicitly a constructor of the super class (as in your example) through a `super(...)` call, it will try to implicitly call the default constructor `super()` (i.e. with no parameters).

Now in your superclass you defined some custom constructors which need parameters, and this implies that there is no more a default constructor, and therefore this situation raises a compilation time error, because you're trying to (implicitly) call a (default) constructor that does not exist in the superclass.

This is the problem that you have: the problem is not about the overriding of constructor (that is an idea conceptually wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the Employee class definition : `CUSTOM(){}` . Alternately, you could try giving a more explicit example with complete code , and that could eventually generate the error you are getting. You make several references to naam and name and interchange them in the Employee class def, which is really confusing

Answer (score 0):

`why you dont need to override all constructors that defined in Super class` .

You are not overriding constructor, What you describe isn't overriding. If you don't specify a default constructor, the compiler will create a default constructor, and If it's a subclass, it will call the default parent constructor, super(), in the default constructor.

You get compiler error because no default constructor for super class is defined

If you add a default superclass constructor

```
Public Employee{
Employee(){}
.
.

}
```

you will not get error

In your case you override the default constructor by defining

```
Person(String name){
this.name=name;
}
```

Read more here http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html